# Spaces in files names in \input or \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, input, external-files, syntax

I'm going crazy...

I have a file I want to include which path is `C:\Users\Matthieu\Documents\Folder withOneSpace\myFile.tex`.
(As you can see with the \, I'm on windows actually)

I tried the following but none works:

```
\input{C:/Users/Matthieu/Documents/Folder withOneSpace/myFile}
\input{C:/Users/Matthieu/Documents/Folder\ withOneSpace/myFile}
\input{C:/Users/Matthieu/Documents/Folder withOneSpace/myFile.tex}
\input{C:/Users/Matthieu/Documents/Folder\ withOneSpace/myFile.tex}
```

I also tried to put the file out of the folder with a space and it works (no surprise):

```
\input{C:/Users/Matthieu/Documents/myFile} --> Works
```

All I found is to put a \ before the space but it doesn't work at all. --> Please help ! :)

Comment: `\input{"File Name"}`  Use quotes

Comment: as Steven said `"` also it's generally easier just to use `\input{myFile}` and arrange that your folder is in the TEXINPUTS path that way your document is portable and avoids the problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried with " before to post but it didn't works because my editor was configure to automatically replace " by some french quote...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the double quote symbol `"`.  In this case, the file `File Name.tex` contained the words `Hello World`

... and `Repin Painting.jpg` contained, well, "Barge Haulers on the Volga" (Russian: Burlaki na Volge, Бурлаки на Волге), best viewed while listening to Lydia Salnikova perform Ah Ty Step Shirokaya http://www.broadjam.com/artists/songs.php?artistID=81353&mediaID=529836.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Testing\par
\input{"File Name"}\par
\includegraphics[width=2in]{"Repin Painting"}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I also tried with " but it didn't works because my editor was configure to automatically replace " by some french quote...
Now it works well