# texmaker and includegraphics cannot find file

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texmaker

I am having trouble including a graph in my TeX document. I am using the `graphicx` packages and set a `\graphicspath` in the preamble. However,

```
\includegraphics{smt.pdf}
```

gives me a file not found error. I've read something about a working directory of pdflatex but have no idea how to alter that in texmaker. The only setting I could find relating to pdflatex is

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Does anyone have the solution?

**EDIT**: MWE (hopefully this is correct):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/Users/../Graphs/} } 
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{leeftijd distributie.pdf} 

\end{document}
```

Thanks,
Dirk

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to just copy your  PDF in the same folder than your `tex`-file? Try also to rename your `.pdf` file without black space.

Comment: It's best practise to avoid spaces and reserved characters in file names, so these errors don't come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the space in the file name of the file you are calling.

As explained in [Spaces in files names in \input or \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191933/64454), you should use the double quote symbol `"` around the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {c:/Users/../Graphs/} } 
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{"leeftijd distributie.pdf"} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks this works (without the .pdf within the quotes). I also had spaces within my graphics folder so also needed quotes in \graphicspath.

Comment: Glad I helped you! Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) if you're satisfied with it. (-:

Comment: I will. Probably still have to wait for the 15 minutes to pass.