# Not able to put figures

Tags: floats, mactex

Please help. I am not able to put figures in Tex in mac.
[image]

Comment: never use spaces in your directories.

Comment: Have you tried removing the blank lines in the `figure` environment?

Comment: Could this be related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191930/spaces-in-files-names-in-input-or-includegraphics ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to include graphics with spaces in their path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/5764)

Comment: You need to load `graphicx` not `graphics` package

Comment: @ArunDebray blank lines in a figure wouldn't generate a runaway argument error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a runaway argument as you are using `graphicx` syntax `[height=...]` with the `graphics` package. You need

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

That will fix the runaway argument error but then as other commenters have noted you will need to use `"` around filenames with spaces, or preferably don't have spaces in filenames.