# Unwanted text above a graph

Tags: graphics

When I run the Latex source file below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{myjust}{\fulljustify}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{BO 2012 1.png}
  \caption{British Open 2012, round 1}
  \label{fig:1} 
\end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{BO 2012 2.png}
   \caption{British Open 2012, round 2}
  \label{fig:2} 
\end{subfigure}%
\captionsetup{justification=myjust,singlelinecheck=false}
\end{center}
\caption{British Open 2012}     
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get in the resulting pdf-file the following unwanted text above the graph.

2012       1.png2012     2.png

How should I change the source file to **not** get that text?

Comment: Do you get any error messages whilecompiling your code? What does the output look like? Do you get the text *instead* of the images or do you get the images *and* the mentioned text?

Comment: Probably unrelated: Do you want to place the images side by side? If yo, they won't fit since 2*{0.55\textwidth} adds up to more than 1\textwidth. Reduce the widths of the two `subfigure` environmens if you want the images to show up side by side.

Comment: Although it can work, I would suggest to not use spaces in file or directory names.

Comment: with a current latex it should work as written with an older latex use `"BO 2012 2".png` with quotes (but not around the .png) but avoiding spaces in filenames is best

Comment: How or where is `\fulljustify` defined?

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to replace both instances of `\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}` with `\begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}` and the first instance of `\end{subfigure}%` with `\end{subfigure}\hfill`.

Comment: Hi leandris  I get the images and the mentioned text. I get the images side by side. I used "BO 2012 2".png with quotes (but not around the .png) and it works.

Comment: Hi David Carlisle,  I used "BO 2012 2".png with quotes (but not around the .png) and it worked. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Spaces in files names in \input or \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191930)