# Compiling error pdflatex cannot find my tex file

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I want to compile my file named *code correcteur.tex* using the terminal, I entered `pdflatex code correcteur.tex` but it keeps telling me that the file cannot be found. I am sure I navigated to the right directory, and I was able to compile another tex. file in the same directory. However, when I typed `dir code correcteur.tex*`, nothing happened. I guess it's  because there's a space in the file name, can someone please tell me why?

Comment: It’s looking for the file code.tex. Put double quotes around the full file name. It’s good practice to not use spaces in file names.

Comment: It's recommended to avoid spaces, especially in programs. There are many a software that go around this issue, like a "Click to open files" thing where spaces are not a problem. However, it's still good practice to replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: The presence of spaces in file names is discussed in this question from a somewhat different perspective: [Spaces in files names in \input or \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191930)

Answer (score 2):

> I guess it's because there's a space in the file name

Exactly. I'm not sure on which operating system you are, but in all operating system the space is used as a separator between program arguments. `pdflatex` therefore sees *two* arguments, `code` and `correcteur.tex`. The first argument which doesn't start with a hyphen is interpreted as the name of the source file (including a `.tex` extension if not specified), and it'll probably try to interpret `correcteur.tex` as a TeX command.

Depending on your operating system, you can either use double quotes around the filename (as @HerbSchulz mentioned in the comments):

```
pdflatex "code correcteur.tex"
```

or *escape* the space:

```
pdflatex code\ correcteur.tex
```

In both cases the operating system will correctly interpret your intention of wanting to specify a single argument.